# Multiple monitors and position of startup object in Winforms app

Tags: winforms

I've taken over maintenance of a Winforms application running on .Net version 4. The startup object is the login form. I have three monitors. The login form opens centered on whatever monitor my mouse pointer is sitting on. I can't find any code in the form that sets it's position. I haven't seen a form do this before. Is there a setting that makes this happen or is this just normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the form's [`StartPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(v=vs.110).aspx) - seems like it's set on `FormStartPosition.CenterScreen`.
From MSDNs page on [FormStartPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition(v=vs.110).aspx) Enumeration:

> ```
> Member name             Description
> CenterParent            The form is centered within the bounds of its parent form.
> CenterScreen            The form is centered on the current display, and has the dimensions specified in the form's size.
> Manual                  The position of the form is determined by the Location property.
> WindowsDefaultBounds    The form is positioned at the Windows default location and has the bounds determined by Windows default.
> WindowsDefaultLocation  The form is positioned at the Windows default location and has the dimensions specified in the form's size.
> ```

Note that `CenterScreen` describes exactly what you described.

Comment: Thanks. I've marked this as the answer because it does answer my question but I found that it isn't always true. There were other forms with the StartPosition set to CenterScreen that were not behaving this way. Those forms would always open in the Primary window. I found that the difference was the form's ShowInTaskbar property. Set to True and the form opens in the current display, as the documentation says. Set to False and the form always opens in the primary display. I would have edited your answer to add this piece of information but I don't seem to have enough privileges yet.